# The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets error while saveChanges in.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have exceptionMiddleware. And it logging all errors to database. But, when working firstly it working perfectly but at second try gave me error during SaveChangesAsync to database. What can be the reason of this error.

**Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency
 injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you
 are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection,
 you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'MyDbContext'.**

**'The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets.'**

MyDbContext.cs

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IAuditHelper auditHelper;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IAuditHelper auditHelper)
        : base(GetOptions())
    {
        this.auditHelper = auditHelper;
    }

    private static DbContextOptions GetOptions()
    {
        return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), "server=asdf; database=asdf; user id=asdf; password=asdf").Options;
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesWithoutAuditAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    services.AddScoped<IJwtHelper, JwtHelper>();
    services.AddScoped<IAuditHelper, AuditHelper>();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

ExceptionMiddleware.cs

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IJwtHelper jwtHelper)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex, unitOfWork, jwtHelper);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IJwtHelper jwtHelper)
    {
        Log log = new Log();
        log.UserIp = jwtHelper.GetValueFromToken("UserIp");

        unitOfWork.LogRepo.AddOrUpdate(log);
        unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. Problem is HandleExceptionAsync method. It must added aync and await like this:

```
  private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IJwtHelper jwtHelper)
    {
        Log log = new Log();
        log.UserIp = jwtHelper.GetValueFromToken("UserIp");

        unitOfWork.LogRepo.AddOrUpdate(log);
        await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.Message);

        return ;
    }
```